# 13.10 No Dolby Digital or DTS passthrough with XMBC

Tags: sound, hdmi, xbmc

I am new Ubuntu User trying to get my feet wet as I am an avid windows user especially in my job.

I have a Lenovo H520s with the Intel G640 processor and built in audio.  I am having a problem with getting Dolby digital and DTS to work properly in XBMC.  When XBMC has the 2 options enabled playback becomes choppy and no sound.  But when I turn off the 2 and only have the Multi channel LPCM enabled it works fine.  I do not want to settle for this as the 5.1 sound is really not as good as it can be.  I have read through many posts and can not seem to find an answer that fits.  I am not sure where the issue is, Ubuntu or XBMC.

All I know is Windows works as need be but XBMC tend to be a bit buggy in windows which is why I am trying linux.

Any thoughts or ideas or help would be appreciated.  Please keep in mind that I don't know linux like I know windows and there fore you need to be detailed.
Thank you!

Comment: How is your receiver connected? If HDMI. did you explicitely configure the sound output to "passthrough"?